# Get camera matrix from OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, computer-vision, projection, camera-calibration

I render a 3D mesh model using OpenGL with **perspective camera** – gluPerspective(fov, aspect, near, far).

Then I use rendered image in a computer vision algorithm.

At some point that algorithm requires camera matrix **K** (along with several vertices on the model and their corresponding projections) in order to estimate camera position: rotation matrix **R** and translation vector **t**. I can estimate R and t by using any algorithm which solves Perspective-n-Point problem.

I construct **K** from the OpenGL projection matrix (see how [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Posit#OpenGL-Projection-Matrix))

**K** = [fX, 0, pX | 0, fY, pY | 0, 0, 1]

If I want to project a model point 'by hand' I can compute:

`X_proj = K*(R*X_model + t)
x_pixel = X_proj[1] / X_proj[3]
y_pixel = X_proj[2] / X_proj[3]`

Anyway, I pass this camera matrix in a PnP algorithm and it works just fine.

---

But then I had to change perspective projection to **orthographic** one.
As far as I understand when using orthographic projection the camera matrix becomes:

**K** = [1, 0, 0 | 0, 1, 0 | 0, 0, 0]

So I changed gluPerspective to **glOrtho**. Following the same way I constructed **K** from OpenGL projection matrix, and it turned out that fX and fY are not ones but 0.0037371. Is this a scaled orthographic projection or what?

Moreover, in order to project model vertices 'by hand' I managed to do the following:

`X_proj = K*(R*X_model + t)
x_pixel = X_proj[1] + width / 2
y_pixel = X_proj[2] + height / 2`

Which is not what I expected (that plus width and hight divided by 2 seems strange...). I tried to pass this camera matrix to POSIT algorithm to estimate R and t, and it doesn't converge. :(

So here are my questions:

1. How to get orthographic camera matrix from OpenGL?
2. If the way I did it is correct then is it true orthographic? Why POSIT doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orthographic projection will not use the depth to scale down farther points. Though, it will scale the points to fit inside the [NDC](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems) which means it will scale the values to fit inside the range [-1,1].
This matrix from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) shows what this means:

[image: Orthographic Projection]

So, it is correct to have numbers other than 1.

For your way of computing by hand, I believe it's not scaling back to screen coordinates and that makes it wrong. As I said, the output of projection matrices will be in the range [-1,1], and if you want to get the pixel coordinates, I believe you should do something similar to this:

```
X_proj = K*(R*X_model + t)
x_pixel = X_proj[1]*width/2 + width / 2
y_pixel = X_proj[2]*height/2 + height / 2
```

Anyway, I think you'd be better if you used modern OpenGL with libraries like [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/index.html). In this case, you have the exact projection matrices used at hand.

Comment: How does K look like in your formula?
Model points project *correctly* when I do the next thing:
K = [f_x, 0, 0 | 0, f_y, 0 | 0, 0, 0] and project with the last formula in my question.

I estimated an affine camera matrix from point correspondences using Gold Standard Algorithm from MVG, Zisserman.
P = 
[0.0032, -0.0001, 0.0017,  614.4414 |
-0.0000, -0.0037, 0, 446.2451 |
0, 0, 0, 1 ]
The value 0.0032 matches f_x, f_y from OpenGL

So, I'm a bit confused which K should I use in CV algorithms when I use glOrtho in OpenGL to generate images, and how to project 'by hand' in this case.

Comment: The K I'm talking about comes from the matrix above, there's no fov, so the f_x,f_y values are just this two scaling factors: `2/width` and `2/height`. You can see more info on this [here](http://ksimek.github.io/2013/06/03/calibrated_cameras_in_opengl/). Getting `X_proj` from this matrix gives a value in the range [-1,1], and from what I understand you want to get screen pixel coordinates in the range [0,width] and [0,height], so you'll need to do as I've shown above.